# shell check if file exist in one line with ssh, then cd, and npm install

Tags: shell-script, shell

I have these lines in my script:

```
ipserver=1.1.1.1
fullpathfile="/var/www/html/mysite"
ssh "root@${ipserver}" "[[ -d ${fullpathfile}/node_modules ]] echo "Directory exist" ||  cd ${fullpathfile} && npm install "
```

But I get this error:

```
Unexpected remote arg: root@1.1.1.1:/var/www/html/mysite/\#012ssh root@1.1.1.1 [[
```

I need to connect through ssh and then check if a folder exist (node_module), if it does not exist, then do: `cd folder` and `npm install`.

what am I doing  wrong ?

Comment: Did you by any chance write the script on a Windows machine? Is it a DOS text file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `[[` (and `[` and `test`) are commands like any other. So you need `&&` to only execute the `echo` if the `[[` succeeds.

```
ssh "root@${ipserver}" "[[ -d ${fullpathfile}/node_modules ]] && echo "Directory exist" || cd ${fullpathfile} && npm install "
```

However, enclosing a series of commands in double quotes like that can get hairy pretty fast, especially if your directory name contains spaces, or your commands need quoted arguments of their own.

To avoid headaches, better to install a little script on the server (for example, as "$HOME/bin/do_npm_install.sh") that does what you need, then invoke that with ssh, like

```
ssh "root@${ipserver}" "bash ~/bin/do_npm_install.sh"
```

Comment: The `~/` _should_ be unnecessary as you will have the home directory as working directory when you `ssh` to a machine.

Comment: *Should* being the keyword. It doesn't hurt to write defensive code.